# is there any such matrix algebra rule

Tags: linear-algebra

I am following a supposedly easy proof of least square approximation through SVD, but I got confused by this step in the proof. Is there any such matrix algebra rule that justifies this?

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $U$ is orthogonal:
\begin{align*}
\|USV^Tx-b\|^2
&= \|USV^Tx-UU^Tb\|^2 \\
&= \|U(SV^Tx-U^Tb)\|^2 \\
&= \|SV^Tx-U^Tb\|^2
\end{align*}
The last step is because orthogonal matrices preserve norms.

Comment: Thanks very much, it's clear now! But isn't the assumption in addition to orthogonality of $U$ also that $U$ is unitary?

Comment: I assumed from the transposes that we were dealing with a purely real situation.  Should they be conjugate transposes?  If so, everything is the same, just with $^\ast$ instead of $^T$.